# Civi AJAX API Search by "AND"ing 2 Tags

Tags: api, tags, javascript

I would like to search the Civi API for Contacts that have both of two tags. I'm at a loss as to how to do this.  Right now if you provide multiple tags, the default is to use an `OR` operation.  For example:

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "tag": [5,7]
  "return": ["tag","first_name"]
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

This currently returns all contacts that have either tag 5 OR tag 7.  I want to return all contacts that have both tag 5 AND tag 7.  Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Sorry, too lazy to open api explorer; just off the top of my head, shouldn't it be something like **"tag": {"IN":5,7}** ?

Comment: I tried `"tag":{"IN":[5,7]}`, but that just did the same thing; it's still an `OR` of the two tags

Comment: Than, may be, try Search Builder (someone has given me same advice somewhere in the past)? Mean find your contacts like this http://imgur.com/d9IPf3f (untested! but seems to be using **AND**,  according to what it says)  , add your findings in a "smart group" and than use API for querying that group? Quite complex path, but at least something..

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.  That doesn't seem like a feasible solution, because it's supposed to be dynamic, i.e. you're supposed to be able to select from several tags, not just two, and find the AND between all of them.  I did look at the search builder; there's no way to use that in the AJAX API, correct?

Comment: Right, it doesn't seems like a solution at all, just a workaround for a very specific issue you've described initially. Just came to mind: you may want to try so called civicrm "chaining" requests, mean, request tag 1 and request tag 2 from tag 1 results.

Comment: Could you tell me how to (or link to a guide on how to) do that?  It's not very well-documented, and I can't figure out how to go about doing that.
Thanks!

Comment: I'd start from here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Chaining

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with one api call.

Not optimal but you could do a postprocess in place of the `// do something` when the result comes.

Better, you could create your own api call in a custom extension - see https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-AddanAPIfunction